# Why doesn't my textview display anything?

Tags: java, android, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

im  currently doing a app that has a barcode scanner. currently when i scanned the barcode it is suppose to display the format of the barcode and the contents also. but currently it doesnt display the format and contents after scanning.

here is the code

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment{

    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    Button scan_btn;
    EditText Edit_current;
    TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        scan_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result.getContents() != null) {
            if (result.getContents() != null){
                String scanContent = result.getContents();
                String scanFormat = result.getFormatName();

                // display it on screen
                formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
                contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/scan_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/scan" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scanFormat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/scan_button" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scanContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/scanFormat" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i have edit the code to this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    scan_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    formatTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanFormat);
    contentTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanContent);
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result.getContents() != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();


    }else{

            String scanContent = result.getContents();
            String scanFormat = result.getFormatName();

            // display it on screen
            formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
            contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
    }
}
}}
```

still cant display the  format and contents

Comment: Where you initialised formatTxt ?

Comment: If you probably remove the outer redundant `if (result.getContents() != null) {` statement, you'll be able to see the failure toast.

Comment: i have change the code to

Comment: @jason I have updated my answer have a look there! tested on my devices. its working

Comment: i used your code and still doesnt display. have debugged thoose lines and they are being not calledout

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your formatTxt & contentTxt in your `onCreateView() method`!
Scan is alright, it just gives NPE because of not initializing `TextView`

```
scan_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
formatTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanFormat);
contentTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanContent);
```

and in your activityResult

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result.getContents() != null) {
            String scanContent = result.getContents();
            String scanFormat = result.getFormatName();

            // display it on screen
            formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
            contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
        }
    }
```

update: that's how it look in your code.

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment{

    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    Button scan_btn;
    EditText Edit_current;
    TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    scan_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    //initialize the textViews 
    formatTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanFormat);
    contentTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanContent);
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (result.getContents() != null) {
                    String scanContent = result.getContents();
                    String scanFormat = result.getFormatName();

                    // display it on screen
                    formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
                    contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
                }else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: hey I'm trying to understand the solution you give but i still dont understand . COuld you provide a sample code as im new to  android studio and trying very hard to learnt it. im really sorry

Comment: i have included my solution in your code. look at the update. and which part you did not understand?

Comment: oh ok now i understand i was confuse on where to inintialise the text view. i hv edit the code with reference with yours but still wont display the text.

Comment: Set Debug pointer at the `formatTxt.setText("");` and check if you are getting values and also if the onActivityResult(..) is even called or not.

Comment: debugged those and there are not being called out

Comment: then check your fragment code and calls. i tested this class as `activity` it works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.sp.ez_mart_xy;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "NAVIGATION");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "HOME");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "PRICE-CHECKER");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my mainactivty but i dont see any errors

Comment: @sadiq this is my main activity could help and take a look at it cost i dont see any error thanks

Answer (score -1):

There are at least two issues with your code:

1. You have the same `if` statement twice:

   ```
   if (result.getContents() != null) {
       if (result.getContents() != null){
   ```

   The outer one does not have an `else`, so you will not know when the condition fails even though the inner one does have an `else`.
2. `formatTxt` is not initialized. You need to add a call to `findViewById()` somewhere in `onCreateView()` to initialize it.